# Which specific fittings can be inserted into a 4" SDR-35 floor pipe without cutting the concrete around it?

Tags: plumbing, basement, drain-waste-vent, fitting

We're interested in installing a clean-out and drain (separately) into our basement floor pipes installed as such:

- 4" SDR-35 PVC pipes
- inner diameter is 3 15/16", outer diameter is 4 3/16"
- the fitting needs to insert into the body of the fitting (not bell) in order to avoid cutting concrete
- we wish to have the final result flush with the concrete slab

Pictures of the scenario:
[image: Cut-off floor pipe, 4" SDR-35 PVC, looking to install drain grate here]
[image: Floor pipe to be cut off, 4" SDR-35 PVC, looking to install cleanout flush with floor]

I've found fittings which can insert into schedule 40 pipe (drain: Sioux Chief 845-4PPK, clean-out: Sioux Chief 875-4P & Oatey 43733) however the ID is different and SDR-35 cannot accommodate these.

Also I've found the [Cherne Inside-Of-Pipe Gripper 270296](https://www.oatey.com/products/cherne-insideofpipe-gripper-1775571796?upc=675115270299) which seems like it would work for the clean-out application, however I would still need to cap the pipe somehow flush with the slab.

Any specific product recommendations or solutions here? I can't be the first to have uncapped 4" SDR-35 sticking out of our slab with a desire to avoid breaking the concrete.

Comment: The SDR-35 is usually used outside the building. Schedule 40 pvc is used inside.  For that reason it is difficult to find fittings . Try a plumbing supply store.  They have many more sources.

Comment: @RMDman thanks for the comment. I'm in Canada where SDR-35 (or DR-35 as noted on the pipes, but I believe it's the same thing) is used in this application. I checked out the big box stores and a couple local plumbing suppliers but had no luck asking for solutions to this situation. I'll order a gripper and fashion a cover out of something if I don't get any other product recommendations.